# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabHost.setup()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I've added a tabwidget in one of my activities.  Just trying to get it to render.  However, app keeps crashing with the above null pointer error.  Getting error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void  android.widget.TabHost.setup()' on a null object reference
```

Here is my activity class:

```
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class DeleteAccountActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

//tabhost
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();
    TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
    TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
    TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third Tab");

    tab1.setIndicator("linearLayout");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, test1.class));

    tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this, test2.class));

    tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(this, test3.class));

    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing 
`(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);` to `(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);`

If that doesn't work, could you post your xml file?

Answer (score 0):

This will be solved if you use `onCreateView` instead of `onCreate`.